# Rails hide/filter admin specific javascript files from user scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to scope some js files only for moderator and admin usage. Normal users who use the application must not see these javascript codes.
How can i do this? Any suggestions would be great..

Comment: why js could be secret? you could simply include files in your dom conditionaly but it really seems weird.

Comment: security does not belong into js. if you really think that it should work this way, you can still serve a js-file from a rails controller that has your favorite way of security or role model.